# Define words in which chars are in alphabetical order

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I'm trying to define which words from a string are sorted in alphabetical order **without** having to cycle over each whole string and compare each char position. I suppose I should make an alphabet string and then somehow compare it to each word of my string using some assembly functions, but now I have no idea how to deal with it.

I've written some code to get a string from console:

```
DATA SEGMENT
    STR1     DB "enter your sring:$"
    STR2     DB "my string is:$"
    INSTR1   DB 250 DUP("$")
    NEWLINE  DB 10,13,"$"
    ALPHABET DB "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"  
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
    ASSUME DS:DATA, CS:CODE
START:    
    MOV AX,DATA
    MOV DS,AX

    LEA SI,INSTR1

    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,STR1
    INT 21H

    MOV AH,0AH
    MOV DX,SI
    INT 21H


    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,NEWLINE
    INT 21H

    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,STR2
    INT 21H

    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,INSTR1+2
    INT 21H

    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,NEWLINE
    INT 21H
CODE ENDS
END START
```

Please give me some advice:
How should I make it?

Comment: It's not really clear what your asking for here.  Maybe give an example of input and what you expect for a result

Comment: You don't actually need an alphabet string. If you convert your input string to all lowercase, you just need to check for each word whether every character has a greater value than the previous (since lowercase ascii is already sorted in ascending order).

Comment: @Shift_Left example string : "qyur abz lmnoy dca",  example result: "abz", "lmnoy"

Comment: @Ben Steffan the fact is that I have to use this string according to my task :(

Comment: @Burning I see. Still, I don't know how exactly you want to achieve this without looping over each word and comparing with you alphabet string. To me it seems this is the only possible way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use function 01h instead of 0Ah. Essentially you're traversing your input one character at a time, but it's done as it's being entered.

```
Loop: mov     cl, al                  ; Move previously read character
      mov     ah, 1
      int     21h
      sub     cl, al                  ; Carry set means we are in ascending order
      ......
      jc      Loop
```

Obviously there is a lot more logic that needs to be done, but analysing at source eliminates the need to point to the beginning of a buffer and traverse through it.  Point is, one way or another, the next character in string/input needs to be compared to the previous one.